# How to remove characters from SpecialChar plugin in CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm trying to remove few special characters from specialchar plugin but it seems impossible.

I've edited lang file in *plugins/specialchar/dialogs/lang/de.js* and removed — and Ñ, but they are still shown in dropdown menu only without hover label.

I've searched everywhere and can't find any more usage of that specialchar menu.

Does anyone know how to remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using newer versions of ckeditor4? if so, based on the [specialchar doc](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4/blob/af6f5152347bcecd5feb6a89a5b7882cc99292a3/plugins/specialchar/plugin.js#L52-L57), you should change the `CKEDITOR.config.specialChars`setting in the `ckeditor4/plugins/specialchar/plugin.js` file.

EDIT: if you are using older version, can you find `config.js` file? if you do, change it to something like below:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';

    config.specialChars = [
        '!', '&quot;', '#', '$', '%', '&amp;', "'", '(', ')', '*', '+', '-', '.', '/',
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ':', ';'];
};
```

It works as shown in this screenshot [showing limited chars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQL6w.png)

Comment: Thanks for responding! But I've already tried that, and the problem with that is ckeditor.js is auto-generated file which I can't edit and I can't find any other implementation elsewhere.

Comment: Hi, I edited my answer. It worked for me, I put a screenshot too. check it out.

Comment: Oh well, don't know how I didn't figure it out. Thank you very much.